# How to remove trailing rows that contain zero of pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with a single column, which ends with some values being zero, like so:

```
index value
0    4.0
1    34.0
2    -2.0
3    15.0
...    ...
96     0.0
97     45
98     0.0
99     0.0
100    0.0
```

I would like to strip away the trailing rows that contain the zero value, producing the following dataframe:

```
index value
0    4.0
1    34.0
2    -2.0
3    15.0
...    ...
96     0.0
97     45
```

How can I do it by leveraging pandas's functions?

I know that I can check the last value of the dataframe iteratively and remove it if it's zero, but I'd rather do it in a way that leverages pandas's built-in function because this would be much faster.

```
while df.iloc[-1,0] == 0:
    df.drop(df.tail(1).index,inplace=True)
```

EDIT: to be clear, the dataframe may or may not contain other zeros. However, I only want to strip trailing zeros, while the other zeros should stay untouched. I have edited the example accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with a reversed [`cummax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cummax.html):

```
out = df[df.loc[::-1, 'value'].ne(0).cummax()]
```

Output:

```
       value
index       
0        4.0
1       34.0
2       -2.0
3       15.0
97      45.0
```

Intermediate:

```
       value   mask
index              
0        4.0   True
1       34.0   True
2       -2.0   True
3       15.0   True
97      45.0   True
98       0.0  False
99       0.0  False
100      0.0  False
```

Alternatively, if you are sure that there is at least one non-zero value:

```
out = df.loc[:df.loc[::-1, 'value'].ne(0).idxmax()]
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the zero values are all stacked at the end of the DataFrame:

```
# find the index of the last non-zero value
last_nonzero_index = df['value'].to_numpy().nonzero()[0][-1]

# create a new DataFrame with only the non-zero rows
new_df = df.iloc[:last_nonzero_index + 1]
```

Otherwise, if they are scattered throughout the DataFrame:

```
# find index of non-zero values
nonzero_index = df['value'].to_numpy().nonzero()[0]

# create a new DataFrame with only the non-zero rows
new_df = df.iloc[nonzero_index]
```

Comment: Thanks but this isn't quite what I need because it assumes that the only zeros are the trailing ones. I have edited my question to make it clear.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with broadcasting

```
df = df[(df != 0.0).any(axis=1)]
```

Comment: Thanks but this isn't quite what I need because it assumes that the only zeros are the trailing ones. I have edited my question to make it clear.

Answer (score 1):

You can compare `value` column with 0 and do a reverse cumsum of the boolean result. The tailing 0 would keep 0 after the cumsum.

```py
out = df[df.loc[::-1, 'value'].ne(0).cumsum()[::-1].ne(0)]
```

```
print(out)

    value
0     4.0
1    34.0
2    -2.0
3    15.0
4     0.0
97   45.0
```